# Update ECS task definition image tag when new image tag

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs, aws-codepipeline

I want my ECS task definition image tag updated when a newer tag exists.

In CodePipeline after I push the image with new tag, I try to update service with the following command, but it doesn't get the new image automatically, still the old one.

```
    - docker push ${DOCKERHUB_USER}/aws-dummy-api:${IMAGE_TAG}
    - aws ecs update-service --cluster my-cluster --service dummy-api-service --force-new-deployment --region eu-central-1
```

So how to get the new image tag automatically when I push a new tag?

Comment: How are you outing the tag in your service/task definition? Or are you using `latest` as the tag?

Comment: @ChrisDoyle in my task definition the image tag is not latest but a previous tag.

Comment: So how are you updating the definition with the new tag?

Comment: So how are you updating the definition with the new tag?

Comment: This is the problem I have.

Comment: OK let me redefine that. How are you deploying your ecs task and its configuration? Is it stored in a git repo somewhere. If so the rightbplace to manage this would be in the git repo and redeploy from the ci.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It seems I need to create a new revison with the new image tag, and update the ECS service.

Following this [github](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk/issues/406#issuecomment-1314183221) issue, I managed like this in my CodePipeline buildspec.yml:

```
build:
    commands:
        - docker build -t $FULL_IMAGE --target prod .
        - docker push $FULL_IMAGE
post_build:
    commands:
        - TASK_DEFINITION=$(aws ecs describe-task-definition --task-definition "$TASK_FAMILY" --region "$AWS_DEFAULT_REGION")
        - NEW_TASK_DEFINITION=$(echo $TASK_DEFINITION | jq --arg IMAGE "$FULL_IMAGE" '.taskDefinition | .containerDefinitions[0].image = $IMAGE | del(.taskDefinitionArn) | del(.revision) | del(.status) | del(.requiresAttributes) | del(.compatibilities) |  del(.registeredAt)  | del(.registeredBy)')
        - NEW_TASK_INFO=$(aws ecs register-task-definition --region "$AWS_DEFAULT_REGION" --cli-input-json "$NEW_TASK_DEFINITION")
        - NEW_REVISION=$(echo $NEW_TASK_INFO | jq '.taskDefinition.revision')
        - aws ecs update-service --cluster ${ECS_CLUSTER} --service ${SERVICE_NAME} --task-definition ${TASK_FAMILY}:${NEW_REVISION}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are missing a step. After the docker push you need to update the task definition (create a new task definition revision) with the new image tag. After that you need to trigger the ECS service to deploy by passing it the `--task-definition` parameter with the new task definition revision ID. And remove the `--force-new-deployment` parameter, as that is for deploying new containers with the current task revision, not for deploying an updated task revision.

Task definitions in ECS are immutable, so you can't just update a value on an existing task definition. You have to create an entirely new revision of the task definition. The CLI tool command to do that would be `aws ecs register-task-definition`. To do this purely through the AWS CLI tool for this, [this](https://doylew.medium.com/updating-aws-ecs-task-definition-and-scheduled-tasks-using-aws-cli-commands-through-deployment-jobs-7cef82262236) looks like a good tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Another idea based on [SuleymanSah's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76084985/4734782):

- Define a `task_definition.json` file and set a placeholder value for the `image` field:

```
{
  "containerDefinitions": [
    "image": "<FULL_IMAGE>"
    ...
  ],
  ...
}
```

You can get the task JSON definition by selecting one of your task revisions on the ECS console, you just need to remove a few fields, which are also listed in the answer I mentioned.

- Then in the `buildspec.yml` file, you can do something like this:

```
...
post_build:
  commands:
    - TASK_DEFINITION=$(jq '.' task_definition.json)
    - TASK_DEFINITION=$(echo "$TASK_DEFINITION" | sed "s/<FULL_IMAGE>/$FULL_IMAGE/g")
    - NEW_TASK_INFO=$(aws ecs register-task-definition --region "$AWS_DEFAULT_REGION" --cli-input-json "$TASK_DEFINITION")
    - REVISION_NUMBER=$(echo "$NEW_TASK_INFO" | jq '.taskDefinition.revision')
    - aws ecs update-service --cluster ${ECS_CLUSTER} --service ${SERVICE_NAME} --task-definition ${TASK_FAMILY}:${NEW_REVISION}
```